# Should we consider arguments of first function as constants for a funtion within the first one?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say we have fun1(L) where L is a list. Fun2(L) is inside of fun1 and L as the argument. I want to mutate L inside of fun2. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of something you've tried?